# Criando um toggle customizado e com animação

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Estou criando um app para Android no qual estou usando um `ToggleButton` como um dos elementos da interface. Estou tentando fazer com que o mesmo tenha imagens ao invés do botão em si e que haja uma transição entre elas (quando o botão é ligado/desligado).

Dando uma pesquisada, li que para usar imagens no botão o melhor seria usando um arquivo xml, o qual está aqui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_off" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

O que não encontrei como fazer é como associar esse arquivo ao botão e como colocar uma transição entre o on/off. Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Eu já havia conseguido alternar as imagens de plano de fundo por código, da seguinte maneira:

```
// botão ligado
mToggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_on));

// botão desligado
mToggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_off));
```

Porém me parece uma maneira pouco ortodoxa, dispondo o Android de recursos mais específicos para se fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Renan, basta usar o atributo `android:background` com esse drawable state list. Não funcionou?

Comment: Obrigado @Wakim, funcionou! O artigo que eu havia encontrado adicionava 3 passos após a criação desse XML para conseguir algo semelhante. Agora só me resta uma dúvida: como eu animo essa mudança de imagens?

Comment: Seria aplicar uma animação de transição entre esses dois estados? Acho que só programaticamente, fazendo um componente que estenda o ToggleButton e dentro do onTouch ou de algum método mais específico que faz a mudança do backgroundDrawable e fazer uma animação (poderia usar um AlphaAnimation (1 para 0), trocar o background e executa outro AlphaAnimation (0 para 1)). Existe também o DrawableAnimation, mas é como se ele fizesse transições entre "frames" (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) e mesmo assim precisa ser iniciada programaticamente.

Comment: Exato, seria aplicar uma transição entre os dois estados. Não é possível fazer sem criar uma nova classe?

Comment: Você pode setar um `OnTouchListener` nesse botão a partir da `Activity` e fazer a animação nele.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Só uma coisa não está certa: quando a animação começa, a imagem de estado some (por exemplo: se está desligado, a imagem de estado desligado some) para então começar a animação de transição. Como eu posso fazer para que a imagem permaneça anteriror permaneça? (algo do tipo imagem 'desligado' > fade > imagem 'ligado', e não imagem 'desligado' > some > fade > imagem 'ligado')

Comment: Usando o `OnTouchListener` acredito eu que duas coisas podem estar ocorrendo: Ou o `Drawable` é trocado antes da chamada do `onTouch` e ai só extendendo a `View`. Ou ele esta trocando depois, mas o fato de iniciar a `Animation`, ele faz após a próxima passada no `layout`, no `startAnimation` ele só configura e invalida a `View` (preciso confirmar o momento correto). No segundo caso teria que fazer a troca manualmente (retorna `false` no `onTouch`, inicia a animação de alpha para 0 troca o `background`, inicia outra de alpha para 1).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16137/discussion-between-renan-lazarotto-and-wakim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer esse efeito, fiz uma classe auxiliar para escutar por eventos de `Motion` no `ToggleButton`, que em sequência:

1. Inicia uma animação de alpha de 1 para 0, deixando o `ToggleButton` transparente.
2. Com o `ToggleButton` transparente modifica o estado dele usando o `setChecked`
3. Depois inicia uma animação de alpha de 0 para 1 para exibir o novo estado.

A classe auxiliar é:

```
public class DrawableTransition extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener, Animation.AnimationListener {

    WeakReference<ToggleButton> mToggle;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    AlphaAnimation mAlphaTo0, mAlphaTo1;

    public DrawableTransition(Context context, ToggleButton toggle) {
        mToggle = new WeakReference<ToggleButton>(toggle);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);

        mAlphaTo1 = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);

        mAlphaTo1.setDuration(1000l);

        mAlphaTo0 = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);

        mAlphaTo0.setDuration(1000l);
        mAlphaTo0.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Animacao de alpha para 0 terminou, vamos mostrar o botao
        show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Delega para o GestureDetector
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    // Single tap foi confirmado
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return hide();
    }

    // Troca o estado, com isso alterando o background
    // depois iniciando uma animacao de alpha para 1, exibindo o botao novamente
    boolean show() {
        ToggleButton toggle = mToggle.get();

        if(toggle == null) {
            return false;
        }

        toggle.setChecked(! toggle.isChecked());

        toggle.startAnimation(mAlphaTo1);

        return true;
    }

    // Faz a animacao de alpha para 0, escondendo o botao
    boolean hide() {
        ToggleButton toggle = mToggle.get();

        if(toggle == null) {
            return false;
        }

        toggle.startAnimation(mAlphaTo0);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Limpar recursos, a fim de evitar memory leak
     * Chamar no onDestroy ou onDestroyView
     */
    public void clean() {
        mGestureDetector = null;
        mToggle.clear();
        mToggle = null;
        mAlphaTo0 = mAlphaTo1 = null;
    }
}
```

Acabei usando o `GestureDetector`, porque trabalhar apenas no `onTouch` pode haver falsos positivos de `ACTION_UP`. O `ACTION_UP` também ocorre quando ele levanta o dedo fora do botão, e isso é caracterizado como um cancelamento. O `GestureDetector` consegue fazer esse tratamento, logo é mais fácil utiliza-lo.

Para usar:

```
ToggleButton toggle = findViewById(...);

toggle.setOnTouchListener(new DrawableTransition(getApplicationContext(), toggle));
```

Comment: acho que estou fazendo algo de errado... usando a classe que você postou, o botão apenas dá fade entre os estados, mas não executa o que deveria executar... eu devo colocar os códigos do que eu quero que ele faça dentro de algum lugar da classe?

Comment: Como assim não faz o que deveria? Seria o processamento do `OnClickListener`? Nesse caso sim, com o `return true` ele não faz, ai é só você chamar logo depois do `hide` dentro do `onSingleTapConfirmed`. Ou seria a troca de `background`?

Comment: Desculpe a enorme demora em responder, acabei deixando esse projeto de lado por um tempo por conta de outros projetos. O fade que eu desejo é o seguinte: o estado inicial (off) fica visível durante a transição e o fade ocorre somente no segundo estado (on). Seria como se fosse uma sobreposição com um fade-in. A sua classe está fazendo com que o estado inicial (off) suma e depois o estado final (on) apareça. Eu poderia tentar fazer eu mesmo com base em sua classe, mas como disse, acabei parando o projeto por um tempo.

Comment: @RenanLazarotto, agora entendi. Da forma que eu fiz, apenas usando o estado da própria `View` não tem como fazer. Para fazer da forma como quer, terá que fazer uma `Custom View`, usando um `FrameLayout` (para ter profundidade) e dois `ImageView's` ou dois `Toggle's`, aplicando `AlphaAnimation` para fazer a transição.